# Unable to get the sum of largest files due to longer than 255 characters deep?

Tags: powershell, robocopy

How can I get the result of the below script when the directory path is longer than 255 characters the files are more than 3 million + approximately?

```
 (Get-ChildItem N:\Shared Folder\Replicated Files -recurse | Sort-Object length -descending | select-object -first 32 | measure-object -property length -sum).sum /1gb
```

The error I'm getting:

```
Get-ChildItem : Could not find a part of the path 'N:\Shared Folder\Replicated Files...'.
At line:1 char:3
+  (Get-ChildItem N:\Shared Folder\Replicated Files -recurse | Sort-Object length -de ...
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ReadError: (N:\Shared Folder\Replicated Files) [Get-ChildItem], DirectoryNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

Comment: If you run Windows 10 1607 or later, try to [enable long paths](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file#enable-long-paths-in-windows-10-version-1607-and-later).

Answer (score 2):

The `robocopy` command supports file paths longer than 255 characters. You can use the `\L` argument to only list the files found (and their sizes) to the output stream. Adding a few other arguments to clean up the output (for example `\BYTES` to display size as bytes - see the [robocopy help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy) for an explanation of them all)

That gives you the following command to get a listing of all the files and their sizes in bytes:

```
robocopy /L /E /ndl /njh /njs /bytes "N:\Shared Folder\Replicated Files" nocopy
```

which gives you output that looks like this:

```
        New File                     154        C:\Temp\file1.tmp
        New File                 1878884        C:\Temp\file2.tmp
        New File                  119465        C:\Temp\file3.tmp
```

You can then use a regex to parse out the file sizes and sorting and adding using your method, we get this:

```
(robocopy /L /E /ndl /njh /njs /bytes "N:\Shared Folder\Replicated Files" nocopy | %{if($_ -match "New File\W*(\d*)\W*([\w:\\\.]*)"){[int32]$matches[1]}} | sort -Descending | select -first 32 | measure -sum | select -expand Sum) / 1gb
```

Not very elegant, but it should work.